# Reactor Flux - Only emit from Publisher on completion

Tags: project-reactor, reactor, reactor-kafka

I have some Reactor Kafka code that reads in events via a `KafkaReceiver` and writes 1..many downstream messages via 1 or more `KafkaSenders` that are concatenated into a single `Publisher`. Everything is working great, but what I'd like to do is only emit an event from this concatenated senders `Flux` when it is complete (i.e. it's done writing to all downstream topics for any given event, so it does not emit anything for each element as it writes to Kafka downstream until it's done). This way I could `sample()` and periodically commit offsets, knowing that whenever it is that `sample()` happens to trigger and I commit offsets for an incoming event that I've processed all downstream messages for each event I'm committing offsets for. It seems like I could use either `pauseUntilOther()` or `then()` somehow, but I don't quite see exactly how given my code and specific use case. Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Main Publisher code:

```
this.kafkaReceiver.receive()
        .groupBy(m -> m.receiverOffset().topicPartition())
        .flatMap(partitionFlux ->
                partitionFlux.publishOn(this.scheduler)
                        .flatMap(this::processEvent)
                        .sample(Duration.ofMillis(10))
                        .concatMap(sr -> commitReceiverOffset(sr.correlationMetadata())))
        .subscribe();
```

Concatenated KafkaSenders returned by call to `processEvent()`:

```
return Flux.concat(kafkaSenderFluxA, kafkaSenderFluxB)
        .doOnComplete(LOG.info(“Finished writing all downstream messages for incoming event);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `Flux.last()` is what you are looking for:

```
return Flux.concat(kafkaSenderFluxA, kafkaSenderFluxB)
    .doOnComplete(LOG.info(“Finished writing all downstream messages for incoming event)
    .last();
```

Then your `.sample(Duration.ofMillis(10))` would do whatever is available as a last item from one or several batches sent to those brokers. And in the end your `commitReceiverOffset()` would properly commit whatever was the last.

See its JavaDocs for more info:

```
/**
 * Emit the last element observed before complete signal as a {@link Mono}, or emit
 * {@link NoSuchElementException} error if the source was empty.
 * For a passive version use {@link #takeLast(int)}
 *
 * <p>
 * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/last.svg" alt="">
 *
 * <p><strong>Discard Support:</strong> This operator discards elements before the last.
 *
 * @return a {@link Mono} with the last value in this {@link Flux}
 */
public final Mono<T> last() {
```

and marble diagram: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/doc-files/marbles/last.svg

Comment: I had discovered takeLast(1) after posting this but this is even better thanks!

Comment: Ah,  but it is possible the source will be empty, I see this throws an exception in that case. I do have onErrorContinue() operator on both Fluxes, will that allow the Publisher to recover and keep processing with this exception? Seems like I want takeLast(1) in this case.

Comment: See `Mono.onErrorResume(Class<E> type,
   Function<? super E, ? extends Throwable> mapper)` for that `NoSuchElementException`. I believe it has to be just like this `onErrorResume(NoSuchElementException.class, ex -> Mono.empty())`. So, your `flatMap()` in the main flow won't emit anything - nothing will be sampled and nothing committed. And everything will come back to the receiving source for the next batch to poll from Kafka.